# Was it justified to close my question?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed, recommendation-questions

Over the last nine years I raised almost 50 questions, but for the first time a question was closed, because it says it is *"seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries"*: [Move files within a ZIP archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77079273/script-to-move-files-within-zip)

My post ends with:

> Is there a way on Windows to script to move directories within a zip file?

It clearly uses *"to script"*. Also my title refers to *"Script"*. Further, the answer provided a solution how to do this with [7-Zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip). There are 6,264 questions that reference 7-Zip. Should they all be closed? I don't think so.

My home turf is more Java/[JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) and rather than Windows scripting. There, I read several hundreds of questions where e.g. [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) plugins are discussed, how things are done in [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) or [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), which libraries provide certain functionality and a few discuss whether one tool is better suited for beginners than others. All very valuable answers, I believe.

I have a hard time to understand in which way my question differs from the over 6 thousand other 7-Zip-related questions/answers exactly, given that I even didn't asked for 7-Zip, but very neutrally asked. There are even Stack Overflow tags for [PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) and [7-Zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/7zip). What is the point of having these tags, when you should not refer to them? Can you please help me to understand that, to prevent that I create more "off-topic" questions?

Comment: You've no attempt for people to start from so we don't know where you're stuck. People then assume you're looking for a complete implementation i.e. some kind of tool written by someone else to do it which is off-topic.

Comment: And on top of that, the only answer it got was "use this library"...

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't think that's a fair characterization of an answer that provides several lines of Powershell code showing how to do it.

Comment: @RobertLongson I think a larger reason for that (since we don't require people to post an attempt) would be that it tags _both_ [powershell] and [batch-file], which are two entirely different languages.  In fact, one user voted "Needs details or clarity", which I would agree with: it's unclear what programming language the question is looking for.

Comment: @RyanM we don't require it but I do find that lots of questions get closed that don't show an attempt whether we require/like it or not.

Comment: @RobertLongson true, but that could be a reason that the closure might be incorrect (which is what this meta post is asking).

Comment: Anyway, relying on your acceptance of the answer and this meta question, I've edited your question to focus specifically on PowerShell rather than batch, clarified a few other points in it, and reopened it.

Comment: Tangentially, and also to explain the most recent edit to *this* post, it's worth noting that none of the individuals involved are [moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators), but simply community members using [moderation privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation) earned through reputation.  Moderators appear with a diamond next to their name on the main site, and a "♦ Mod" badge on the meta site.

Comment: *What is the point of having these tags, when you should not refer to them?* - Where did you get this from? I don't see any comment telling you not to use these tags. Just because your question was closed does not mean that everything with the same tags should be closed and the fact that a tag exists does not mean that every question is automatically on-topic.

Comment: I still find it a fair question, the source of many discussions on meta without really ever any consensus. It is very confusing especially to the uninitiated to have tags on Stack Overflow which have a very high likelihood to produce off-topic questions but they're "allowed in" because there might be some programming related questions in there. Me personally, I'd rather just have a line drawn in the sand and not have those tags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: It's not off-topic IMO, but it kind of reads like a zero-effort requirements dump as written, so it's arguably too broad (because the only possible answer right now is to do the whole thing for you).

Comment: To be clear: your goal is to *use Powershell commands* to *manipulate the contents* of a zip file? Then you should a) start by giving some reason why you expect this to be possible; b) give a clear, precise specification for a specific manipulation that you want to perform.

Answer (score -4):

No, It was not justified to close the question.

The question is asking for a way to perform an automation task through (windows) shell scripting. Shell scripting is and always has been on-topic on Stack Overflow (source: I have a gold badge in [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash)).

Regarding the complaint that there is no attempted solution in the question body, that as well has never been a valid close reason on SO.

Regarding the argument that you didn't specify the specific input/outputs and thus the question is unclear, that may be a valid close reason in some circumstances, but in this case the task was so easy to understand that I personally don't think that input/output definition was necessary.

In conclusion, the question should never have been closed, and you did the right thing to bring the issue up on meta. Mistakes like this happen from time to time, and it is important to have them corrected, even when the question is already answered, like in this case.